# Installing a hard-disk on Xbox 360 4 GB

Tags: xbox-360

I have a spare 250 GB 2.5" hdd (Western Digital Scorpio Black, 7200RPM) and I'm planning to buy a new Xbox.

Is it possible to buy a 4GB Xbox (which as far as I understand is provided with a 4GB flash memory but has no conventional hdd) and subsequently install such hdd in it?

In addition: does this void the guarantee?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Officially, the Xbox 360 only supports using Microsoft's official Xbox 360 hard drives. These are basically laptop hard drives in a special (Xbox specific) enclosure. Using a standard hard drive is not a supported scenario.

You could buy a USB enclosure and connect your hard drive that way, however you'll only be able to use 16GB of the drive (that is the maximum size USB drive the Xbox would support). I think that you can have multiple USB drives connected, so you could in theory partition it into multiple 16GB partitions and see how that works.

If you want an Xbox 360 with a hard drive, I would suggest buying the 250GB model, since this is generally cheaper than buying the 4GB model and a 250GB hard drive.

Comment: In other words... Microsoft says not to, but if you get the special enclosure (they seem to be easy to find online) and a 2.5" hard drive, you should be good to go?

Comment: @Jefromi In theory, yes. However I personally would use an official hard drive.

Comment: can i install bootlegged games on the new hard drive without purchasing a original game drive

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that; however, if you can find an old 360 hard drive, you can take the drive out of the enclosure, buy a case for it, and then plug it into the slim and be fine. This is what I did with mine. You will need a small torx screwdriver to get the case open.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You have to track down the correct software to make it happen, which may be more challenging now than it used to be in the past.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Adeese 's response, as of now (2018), I was able to successfully install and use much more than 16 GB on a USB drive; currently, I'm using about 100 GB (out of 300 GB) with no problems.
There may have been an update from Microsoft in the intervening years to allow for more memory usage from connected USB drives.