# Do I need an official Hard Drive for Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing a hard-disk on Xbox 360 4 GB](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22593/installing-a-hard-disk-on-xbox-360-4-gb)

I am thinking of getting a new hard drive for my Xbox 360 (4 GB). I was looking at http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Xbox360/Accessories/HardDrives/Home and it looks like they only have 1 which seems overpriced as I could purchase a 1 TB hard drive for the same amount.

Do I have to get that one to work for my Xbox or can I buy a cheap 3rd party one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, the Xbox 360 only works with certain models of hard drives.  I know that the old (fat?) Xbox 360s could use certain Seagate drives and certain programs to make it think it's an Xbox 360 drive.

However, I believe this trick no longer works for the Xbox 360 S.

Sony saw this decision and decided to use the PS3's ability to use any 2.5" drive in their early PS3 advertising.

Comment: I've heard tell of people using their own drives in the new enclosures, but it's all hear-say.