# the capability to use external hard drive on xbox 360 is unlimited?

Tags: xbox-360, hardware, hard-drive

Hello I read in these questions:

- [Could I use a 1/2TB USB 2/3 external HDD with an XBox 360?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78314/could-i-use-a-1-2tb-usb-2-3-external-hdd-with-an-xbox-360)
- [Installing a hard-disk on Xbox 360 4 GB](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22593/installing-a-hard-disk-on-xbox-360-4-gb)

These  question explain than can only be used 16 GB (or 32 GB partitioned) in a external USB storage Device on an Xbox 360

Listen to co-workers that a new update for Xbox 360 allows you to use the full capacity of a hard drive, for example a 1 TB external hard drive, but I have not found anything on  the internet.

Is this true?

Comment: why marked as duplicate?, I ask if in the future will be unlimited storage

Comment: Then it should have been closed because it's speculating on unreleased content instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 1 TB hard drive I hooked up to my Xbox and it will only use 32 GB on the 1 TB hard drive. As far as I know. you have to get a special NTFS hard drive made by Microsoft to use with your Xbox.

Comment: There is nothing special about the hdd that Microsoft sells besides be in the enclosure

Answer (score 0):

The authoritative source for Xbox 360 storage-related info is [Microsoft:](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/storage)

> Why does Xbox 360 only support 32GB of storage, even though I have a much larger device?
>
> Supporting USB storage devices up to 32GB in size is a huge increase in storage over any solid state memory storage solutions currently available for Xbox 360.

(Note that this has increased from 16 to 32 GB since the last time we covered this topic)

I also tried plugging in a 64 GB USB key into my Xbox 360 today, and it only let me use 32 GB.  My Xbox 360 is patched to the latest.  As far as I know, there's no beta patch or  other plans to increase this.